# Fortran polymorphic array assignment for `PACK`: issues

Tags: arrays, fortran, polymorphism

I am trying to code a computationally efficient `PACK` operation over a polymorphic array and I am running on issues with `gfortran 9.2.0`:

- The `PACK` operation has to work on a polymorphic array of a derived type quantity, and return a result on itself
- For reasons I'm not explaining here, this array should *not* be reallocated
- In general, there is overlap between the locations of the returned indices, and those of the original array: something like `array(1:5) = array([2,4,6,8,10])`

I'm having problems, as the only version of the assigment I've tried with gfortran is with a loop - all array-based version either produce compiler or runtime segfaults.

An example is reported in this program:

```
module m
   implicit none
   
   type, public :: t
      integer :: i = 0
      contains
      
      procedure, private, pass(this) :: t_assign => t_to_t
      generic :: assignment(=) => t_assign
   end type t
   
   type, public, extends(t) :: tt
      integer :: j = 0
      contains
      procedure, private, pass(this) :: t_assign => t_to_tt
   end type tt
   
   contains
   
   elemental subroutine t_to_t(this,that)
      class(t), intent(inout) :: this
      class(t), intent(in   ) :: that
      this%i = that%i
   end subroutine t_to_t
   
   elemental subroutine t_to_tt(this,that)
      class(tt), intent(inout) :: this
      class(t ), intent(in   ) :: that

      this%i = that%i
      select type (thatPtr=>that)
         type is (t)
            this%j = 0
         type is (tt)
            this%j = thatPtr%j
         class default
            ! Cannot stop here
            this%i = -1
            this%j = -1
      end select        
   end subroutine t_to_tt
      
end module m

program test_poly_pack
   use m
   implicit none
   
   integer, parameter :: n = 100
   integer :: i,j
   class(t), allocatable :: poly(:),otherPoly(:)
         
   allocate(t :: poly(n))
   allocate(t :: otherPoly(10))
   
   ! Assign dummy values
   forall(i=1:n) poly(i)%i = i
   
   ! Array assignment with indices => ICE segfault:
   ! internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
   otherPoly(1:10) = poly([10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100])
   
   ! Scalar assignment with loop -> OK
   do i=1,10
     otherPoly(i) = poly(10*i)
   end do
   
   ! Array assignment with PACK => Compiles OK, Segfault on runtime. GDB returns: 
   ! Thread 1 received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
   ! 0x000000000040163d in m::t_to_t (this=..., that=...) at test_poly_pack.f90:31
   ! 31                this%i = that%i


   otherPoly(1:10) = pack(poly,mod([(j,j=1,100)],10)==0)

   do i=1,10
     print *, ' polymorphic(',i,')%i = ',otherPoly(i)%i
   end do   
   
end program test_poly_pack
```

Am I doing anything wrong, and/or is this only a compiler bug or there is any best practices I should be following?

Comment: You really should show your error messages. And also update your compiler. Do you get a message saying that the intrinsic assignment must not be polymorphic? Note that `allocate(otherPoly(1:10),source = pack(poly,mod([(j,j=1,100)],10)==0))` works.

Comment: If you get a segfault in the compiler, it is a bug in the compiler. You must report that to GCC, we really can't help you with that. The error message says **Please submit a full bug report**. What is your exact question?

Comment: thanks, I've added error-related outputs

Comment: The question is what is the best practice for this: as the array versions seem to have issues, what is a computationally efficient implementation which does not need temporary allocation?

Comment: Well, I do not see what could be the answer for that, obviously that depends on the bugs in the compiler, I do not see that you would be doing anything wrong. Are you just looking for a workaround? Reallocating might be the best for the time being. Until the bugs you have reported get fixed. Or use a compiler that does not have these bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crashes are compiler bugs. When the compiler says **internal compiler error ... Please submit a full bug report,** you really can trust it and you should act accordingly (and submit the bug report). The runtime crash is a compiler bug as well (wrong code).

If you know the actual types at the time of the assignment, you can use type guards

```
   select type (p => poly)
     type is (t)
       select type(op => otherpoly)
         type is (t)
           op(1:10) = pack(p,mod([(j,j=1,100)],10)==0)
       end select
   end select
```

If you need it to be polymorphic - you probably have to reallocate

```
allocate(otherPoly(1:10),source = pack(poly,mod([(j,j=1,100)],10)==0))
```

until the bugs you hopefully reported are fixed.

Comment: Thanks, both your workarounds work fine with `gfortran`. As you're also saying, they  are both not very much in the spirit of object-oriented programming - which (when it works) drastically simplifies syntax. When posting this question, I thought that it was very basic OO stuff even for Fortran, that I must have done something wrong.

Comment: @FedericoPerini I do not know how to repeat it more clearly. IT IS A COMPILER BUG. There is nothing wrong you have done. You should report the bug to GCC. That's all.